# latitude and longitude mysql column FLOAT(10,6) vs DECIMAL(10,6)

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

For Latitude and Longitude fields Should I use FLOAT(10,6)? or DECIMAL(10,6)?

which one is optimal for MySql? I can add an index using PhpMyAdmin to both fields to make them searchable, I just am wondering which type will work best without Mysql changing anything I import.

Comment: You can now use (geo)spatial data types. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html for more informations.

Comment: I added the table, then clicked alter (using PhpMyAdmin), and changed the type to Geometry, but it won't let me create that, because I don't know the length, if I put 10,6, it gives me an error. What length should I put?

Comment: You will never get 16 decimal digits of accuracy from either FLOAT or DOUBLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no valid reason to put `(M,N)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  It causes a second rounding.  Some choices:

```
                    bytes     Resolution
DECIMAL(6,4)/(7,4)     7    16 m     52 ft
FLOAT                  8   1.7 m    5.6 ft
```

As for "optimal", it depends on what you will do with them.

[Geometry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-datatypes.html) is probably overkill for most applications.  See what is involved before launching into that area.